# Embed PNG images in PDF file without bloat

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images, print-to-pdf, pdfcreator

I'd like to save a document as PDF without any loss in picture quality, with sensible file size.

PNG images were imported to the Microsoft Word document. The advantage of PNG format is lossless compression which makes it suitable for schematics or blueprints (as it doesn't damage lines and edges). I don't know how Word stores it internally, but it works. These images are still pixel-to-pixel equal to original (not distorted). The filesize of DOCX is similar to PNG which was imported into. That's what I'd like to achieve with PDF.

I've tried PDF Creator with option Format >> PDF >> Compression >> Color and greyscale >> ZIP. It works. Image quality is ok, but the PDF file size is way too big. It can be tens of times bigger (e.g., 100 MB) than the original DOCX or PNG.

How can I force PDF to store graphics internally as PNG or other efficient format that ensures good file size?